# Bootstrap 4 columnas en pantallas grandes y renglones (líneas) en pantallas pequeñas

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola alguien me ayuda : este es mi codigo

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
```

## 1

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
```

## 2

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" >
```

## 3

Lo que quiero lograr es lo siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

para utilizar columnas necesitas tenerlas dentro de un "row".

También tienes que cerrar los divs, otra cuestión solo necesitas especificar límites, por ejemplo solo establezco medidas para "md" que también se aplicará a "lg" y al asignarle a "sm" también aplica para "xs" (que en bootstrap 4 me parece que solo es col)

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">Aqui esta el contenido</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">Aqui esta el contenido</div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">Aqui esta el contenido</div>
  </div>
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando acá 
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ELCAbPFd0cYV2ZZo?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza un **div** con la clase **row** para contenerlas y que pueda hacer el comportamiento que tu quieres y para el ordenamiento colocas la clase `order-` donde indicas con el número la posición ejemplo `order-3`:

```css
div[class^="col-"]{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center order-1">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center order-3">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center order-2">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Queria lograr esto amigos :      1   3    2

Comment: Tienes razón ya te lo modifico

Comment: Listo ya modifique para que te funciones como quieres.